# How to Change the Port of Appium UiAutomator2 Server running in emulator?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am facing an issue with port forwarding in my Appium setup, particularly with the UiAutomator2 server running on my Android emulator.

In the Appium server logs, I noticed the following lines:

```
Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@6e6a (86b8ae39)] Forwarding UiAutomator2 Server port 6790 to local port 8200
[ADB] Forwarding system: 8200 to device: 6790
```

This indicates that the UiAutomator2 server is being forwarded from port 6790 to local port 8200 using the command (found in appium server logs):

```
adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8200 tcp:6790
```

However, due to restrictions in my environment (specifically, running the emulator in a container with limited open ports), I need to change the port of the UiAutomator2 server to a specific port i.e from ***6790*** to ***2026***.

I have already explored adjusting the system port by adding "systemPort": 8202 in my capabilities, but this only changes the local port to 8202 instead of addressing the issue with the UiAutomator2 server port.

Here are the capabilities I currently use for my emulator:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554"
}
```

I have verified that the UiAutomator2 server is running properly by accessing http://127.0.0.1:6790/status in Chrome, which confirms that UiAutomator is ready to connect.

Is there a way to change the port of the UiAutomator2 server from the default port `6790` to a custom port `2026`, within the Appium setup, considering the constraint of not being able to open specific ports in my environment??